# about query analyzer

Tags: sql-server-2005

_I use sql server 2005 and I want to execute mu store procedure like  `exec <procedure_Name> ' ',' ',' '`
so for this I need query analyzer window but I can not find please help me

_also is there any check syntax box in sql server 2005?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, in SQL Server 2005, the whole of Query Analyzer was rolled into Sql Server Management Studio (you can get the Express version [for free](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=C243A5AE-4BD1-4E3D-94B8-5A0F62BF7796&displaylang=en), if you don't have a full license). Also, you can perform syntax checking simply by [turning off execution](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/validatingsql.aspx) in your T-SQL batch.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server 2005, Query Analyzer has been replaced with SQL Server Management Studio. There is a toolbar button for syntax checking.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Management Studio click `New Query` at the top left, or right-click your stored procedure and go `Script Stored Procedure As -> EXECUTE To -> New Query Editor Window`.

You can check the syntax of a query (somewhat) by clicking the "Tick" on the toolbar (it is the Parse button). However, it is not completely accurate.

Comment: aha I have saved my stored procedure but there is not in the stored procedure option,why?

Comment: You can't see the procedure under DB -> Programmability -> Stored Procedures or you can't see "Script as" when you right-click your Stored Procedure?